# Regular expressions in ignored_words in Sublime Text 3 spell_check?

Tags: regex, latex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to spellcheck a latex file. I would like the spellchecker to ignore strings containing a number. In my settings file I have

```
"ignored_words":
[
    "textbf",
    "renewenvironment",
    etc...
]
```

If I add something like `".*[0-9].*"` to `"ignored_words"` it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you check wild cards: `"*[0-9]*"`?

Comment: ST issue https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1299

Comment: ST uses [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io) as its spell checker. Adding regex to Hunspell is an [open feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/hunspell/feature-requests/34/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use regex in spell checking at this point.

ST uses [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io) as its spell checker. Adding regex to [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io) is an open [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/hunspell/feature-requests/34/). Not being closed means there is some hope that it may be on a long term enhancement list, maybe.

Until [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io) adds this capability it seems impossible to achieve what you are seeking in ST.

Keeping an eye on the feature request may be worth it to see if there is any progress.